# Is there a way to geofence (block) iPhone data usage?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, parental-controls

I am trying to figure out a way to block data usage when an iPhone is in a certain location, specifically, my home.

The use case is this: The phone is my child's. The phone uses WiFi at home. The WiFi network is blocked (by me) at the router level until responsibilities are taken care of (homework, etc.). But when WiFi is not available, the phone just uses the data network. This both subverts the screen time management plan, and eats up the device's monthly data limit (necessary to prevent absurd cell phone bills). I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve physically taking the phone away.

Solutions could involve:

1. iPhone settings (seems easiest to me, if there is a way to do it)
2. Parental control software/apps such as NetNanny or Qustodio
3. Carrier-level settings--in which case I can provide information about my carrier, though I'm not sure that carriers provide geofencing

Comment: Have you set most apps to wifi only?

Comment: No. That might make sense for a few apps, not necessarily all of them. I would have to think about that. For example, I wouldn't really want my child to be unable to use Messages on data when out in public, I just don't want them using Messages when they're home and the WiFi is locked.

Comment: Makes sense for my apps and data use...

Comment: Lock the phone in a drawer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shortcuts app to create a shortcut that turns cellphone data on or off at a certain time, or when a text from you which contains a specific word is received, plus several other triggers.